# How to change DEX version to 37 while maintaining targetSdkVersion at 30?

Tags: android, dex

I am trying to wrap an apk on the mobileiron website, but I got an error. I opened a ticket and I got the following response from support: "I see that the DEX version for the app is 39. I would require you to change the DEX support to 37 and test the same again."

How to change the DEX version to 37 while maintaining targetSdkVersion at 30?

Answer (score 0):

DEX version is based on minSdkVersion, not targetSdkVersion, so targetSdkVersion can remain at 30